# How to sort data getting from an endpoint in javascript using react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[I want to sort the items according to their Id like in ascending so how to do it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ixyq.jpg)

heres the code from react component i used...

```
import { useState, useEffect} from "react"
//styles
import './ItemList.css'

export default function ItemList() {

const[Items,setItems]=useState([])


useEffect(() => {

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/data')
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(json=>setItems(json))
   
}, [])


console.log(Items)

return (
    <div className="item-list">
        <h1>Item List</h1>
        <ul>
            {Items.map(data=>(

            <li key={data.id}>
            <h2>{data.id}</h2>
            <h3>{data.name}</h3>
            </li>

            ))}
        </ul>
        
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: The best method is to include pagination and sort in API itself. if you need it in UI `then(json=>setItems(json.sort(....//your sort condition)))
 `

Comment: Agreed. Ideally that would be done on the server, but if it has to be front-end the answer below will work

Answer (score 2):

Pagination might create problems if you sort on the front end.

use array sort for frontend, I'm assuming id is number

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/data")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => setItems(json.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)));
```

If it's a string

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/data")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => setItems(json.sort()));
```

Comment: Note: This is assuming `item.id` is type `number`. (I think it probably is, too.)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.